# 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, security, mysql-error-1064

I deployed my ASP.NET project on host but take this fail. I am trying to solve this issue for hours but could not.
On my first page users enter email and password after click login button they navigate menu. All datas store in mysql db. After publish i could not see mysqldata.dll in bin folder so i have added manually.

Please help me to solve this issue. I should deploy in 2 days.

This issue is displaying after while i am trying to login.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Security Exception

Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file. 

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Source Error: 


[No relevant source lines]

Source File: App_Web_0twfxhxf.8.cs    Line: 0 

Stack Trace: 


[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.AssertPermissions() +0
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() +190
   gop.Default.loginbutton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +216
   System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e) +0
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9628722
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +6704
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +245
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +72
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +21
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +58
   ASP.default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in App_Web_0twfxhxf.8.cs:0
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +341
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

This is web.config file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <appSettings>

    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />

    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0"/>
  </appSettings>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySqlConnectionString" connectionString="Server=xxx;Database=xxx;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;charset=utf8;Integrated Security=false"
   providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>

    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="true"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.0" />

  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

I have tried to add `<trust level="Medium" />` in web.config file but after that even first page can not display and give down issue.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using <location allowOverride="false"> from an inherited configuration file.

Source Error: 


An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Source File: D:\inetpub\xxx.com\www\web.config    Line: 24
```

Comment: Does your hosting company claim to support MySql? The problem is that they have THEIR trust level set such that security is failing trying to open the connection. You may either need to contact their support to look for working examples or switch to a host that supports MySql.

Comment: Yes they support MySql and their trust level is medium. I am new in c# and asp.net so is my web.config file true? is there any mistake on it?

Comment: Did you try setting <trust level="Full" />?  This is the sort of error that occurs normally when you are already at medium trust.

Comment: Yes I tried but did not work.

Comment: @Onur, you need to check the main site on your IIS, Maybe you website is inside a root website with low trust level.  https://help.webcontrolcenter.com/kb/a1110/how-do-i-change-my-websites-trust-level-_net-windows.aspx

Comment: For full trust level My host will support for full trust level. But I am not sure it will be okey after set full trust level. I think my web.config file seems clearly bad. I have used itextsharp, mysql but it has not any permission about it.

Is there any mistake in web.config? 
If I set my host full trust level will it work?

www.natro.com is my host.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.
Put in your Web.config.

```
<system.web>
 <securityPolicy>
   <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal"/>
 </securityPolicy>
</system.web>
```

About the  mysqldata.dll, go to the reference, click on  mysqldata.dll, right button, properties, and check if Copy Local is set to true.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have put but it did not work. Same issue again. If I pay more money for full trust level My host will support for full trust level. But I am not sure it will be okey after set full trust level. I think my web.config file seems clearly bad. I have used itextsharp, mysql but it has not any permission about it.

Is there any mistake in web.config? 
If I set my host full trust level will it work?

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

I have talked with my host company and they set `TRUST LEVEL FULL` after i set my application framework v3.5.

How did i do that?

Right Click Project- Properties - Select Application from Left Bar - Choose Target Framework 3.5. After these publish and deploy.

My web.config seems like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
          <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
          <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connstrname" connectionString="server=xxx;database=xxx;uid=xxx;password=xxx;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime/>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
      <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
          <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
          <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
      <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptResource" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try put in your Web.config:

```
<system.web>
..
<trust level="Full" originUrl="" />
..
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you have to open web.config file at this path: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config` 
At second, you have to find this line under section 
`system.web` 
`trust level="Medium" originUrl=""` 
And at last: you have to change it like that:
`trust level="Full" originUrl=""`

### if you will this change you can solve your security problem..

Comment: how do we do this on godaday server?

Answer (score 0):

Go to plesk panel. and asp.net settings. CAS policy level. change MEDIUM to FULL.