# How to increase Trust Levels of a "Class Library" Project?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

Is it possible to increase the trust level of my Class Library project?  I constantly encounter permission errors such as

Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

This is not the only permission error I had, as I also had one related to MySQL when trying to make a simple connection.  I assume the solution to solve this will be to allow full trust on my project, but I do not see that option in my properties as there is no "Security" tab.

Is there a way to allow full trust for my class library project to avoid these errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31015214/system-security-permissions-securitypermission-mscorlib-version-4-0-0-0-cult

Comment: Since my project is a Class Library, it does not have a web.config file associated with it.  But within the first part of the OP's solution, they mention that their host company set their Trust Level to full.  How do I do this for a Class Library?  I traditionally have never had this issue with any other project, it seems like my current project (Class Library) rejects all permissions of my assemblies.  Also since I do not have a web.config, is it possible to set trust level to full in my packages.config?

Comment: I think, that the trust level must be set in startup project of your application, rather than in class library

Comment: I did not see an option for this.  As a create a new Class Library Project from scratch but was never given a option to change this preference.